# Curious sporadically performance problems of select count(*) query after upgrading to SQL Server 2012 (from 2005)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ado

We have a native C++ COM application for controlling our production lines. The application is using ADO to access a MS SQL server. Server part of application is running on Windows Server 2003 and Clients XP. Recently we switched from SQL SERVER 2005 to SQL SERVER 2012 (but database remaining in 2005 compatibility modus). The migration was quite smooth (just 1/2 downtime). Old server and clients are in same domain, new server is in a different domain (of course trusted). Authentication is done by SQL Server authentication. However now i got complaints about a sporadic performance degration on a specific action on a packaging client station. By putting some debug output into the code, i could find the involved code and this code executes a "select count(*) from TableX where col = ?" query (not prepared). The table has max. of some thousand entries and where column is indexed. Isolation level is committed read. Blocking should not be an issue because there are only updates and inserts of single lines. But even mass updates should not be an issue with some thousand rows.

This query performs in milliseconds most of the time but sometimes it needs around 10 seconds. Here is the code block used to execute SQL statements.

```
HRESULT CCxADORecordset::OpenSQL(CString strSQL, CursorTypeEnum eCursorType, LockTypeEnum eLockType)
{
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
CCxDataLogger dataLogger("CxDBServerLib");

CString strDebug;
strDebug.Format("CCxADORecordset::OpenSQL2: BeforeGetRecordSet (%s)\n", strSQL);
OutputDebugString(strDebug);

SET_SUCC_HR(hr, GetRecordset());

COleVariant varSQL(strSQL);

bool fFinished = false;
long lRetryCount = 1;

do
{
    OutputDebugString("CCxADORecordset::OpenSQL2: BeforeOpen\n");
    SET_SUCC_HR(hr, m_pIRecordset->Open(varSQL, g_varEmpty, eCursorType, eLockType, adCmdText));

    OutputDebugString("CCxADORecordset::OpenSQL2: BeforeGetExecuteRetry\n");
```

LockType and CursorType could be configured by registry entries and are set to adLockOptimistic and adOpenKeyset.

This is some sample debug output

```
01308272    13:46:24.701    [2964] CCxADORecordset::OpenSQL: BeforeGetDefaultCursorType
01308273    13:46:24.701    [2964] CCxADORecordset::OpenSQL: BeforeGetDefaultLockType
01308274    13:46:24.701    [2964] CCxADORecordset::OpenSQL: BeforeOpenSQL2
01308275    13:46:24.701    [2964] CCxADORecordset::OpenSQL2: BeforeGetRecordSet (SELECT Count(*) As lCount              FROM ProdArtikel        WHERE lWTNr = -2)
01308276    13:46:24.701    [2964] CCxADORecordset::OpenSQL2: BeforeOpen
01308277    13:46:33.717    [2964] CCxADORecordset::OpenSQL2: BeforeGetExecuteRetry
01308278    13:46:33.717    [2964] CCxADORecordset::OpenSQL2: AfterGetExecuteRetry
01308279    13:46:33.717    [2964] CCxADORecordset::OpenSQL: AfterOpenSQL2
01308280    13:46:33.717    [2964] CommonHelper::isWTEmpty() Before getFieldValue
01308281    13:46:33.717    [2964] CommonHelper::isWTEmpty() Before Close
```

and only milliseconds later

```
01308300    13:46:33.732    [2964] CCxADORecordset::OpenSQL: BeforeGetDefaultCursorType
01308301    13:46:33.732    [2964] CCxADORecordset::OpenSQL: BeforeGetDefaultLockType
01308302    13:46:33.732    [2964] CCxADORecordset::OpenSQL: BeforeOpenSQL2
01308303    13:46:33.732    [2964] CCxADORecordset::OpenSQL2: BeforeGetRecordSet (SELECT Count(*) As lCount              FROM ProdArtikel        WHERE lWTNr = -2)
01308304    13:46:33.732    [2964] CCxADORecordset::OpenSQL2: BeforeOpen
01308305    13:46:33.748    [2964] CCxADORecordset::OpenSQL2: BeforeGetExecuteRetry
01308306    13:46:33.748    [2964] CCxADORecordset::OpenSQL2: AfterGetExecuteRetry
01308307    13:46:33.748    [2964] CCxADORecordset::OpenSQL: AfterOpenSQL2
01308308    13:46:33.748    [2964] CommonHelper::isWTEmpty() Before getFieldValue
01308309    13:46:33.748    [2964] CommonHelper::isWTEmpty() Before Close
```

It seems to only this query having the performance issues sometimes.

I activated the snapshot isolation level for the database which didn't help.I activated SQL server extended events (with blocked process treshold set to 5 seconds) to produce a blocked process report. It didn't create any output.

I run SQL Server trace. It shows the same SQL execution time of 0 ms for both the first and second execution of the statement.

```
SQL:BatchStarting                   SELECT Count(*) As lCount                  FROM ProdArtikel                    WHERE lWTNr = -2 CxFrame     2964    DEL10   sigma           256 2016-04-28 13:46:25.697             LINIE10-4   16      22078966    1       0XAF4C8D9B17C7A24FB9D948FA565A9898      0       ZDELINESQL2\DEPRODUCTION    sigma       0                                   
SQL:StmtCompleted   0   2016-04-28 13:46:25.697         SELECT Count(*) As lCount                  FROM ProdArtikel                    WHERE lWTNr = -2 CxFrame 0   2964    DEL10   sigma       2   256 2016-04-28 13:46:25.697 0           LINIE10-4                                                                                       
SQL:BatchCompleted  0   2016-04-28 13:46:25.697         SELECT Count(*) As lCount                  FROM ProdArtikel                    WHERE lWTNr = -2 CxFrame 0   2964    DEL10   sigma       2   256 2016-04-28 13:46:25.697 0           LINIE10-4   16  0 - OK  22078967    1       0XAF4C8D9B17C7A24FB9D948FA565A9898      0   1   ZDELINESQL2\DEPRODUCTION    sigma       0           

SQL:BatchStarting                   SELECT Count(*) As lCount                  FROM ProdArtikel                    WHERE lWTNr = -2 CxFrame     2964    DEL10   sigma           256 2016-04-28 13:46:34.743             LINIE10-4   16      22079361    1       0XAF4C8D9B17C7A24FB9D948FA565A9898      0       ZDELINESQL2\DEPRODUCTION    sigma       0                                   
SQL:StmtCompleted   0   2016-04-28 13:46:34.747         SELECT Count(*) As lCount                  FROM ProdArtikel                    WHERE lWTNr = -2 CxFrame 0   2964    DEL10   sigma       2   256 2016-04-28 13:46:34.747 0           LINIE10-4                                                                                       
SQL:BatchCompleted  0   2016-04-28 13:46:34.743         SELECT Count(*) As lCount                  FROM ProdArtikel                    WHERE lWTNr = -2 CxFrame 0   2964    DEL10   sigma       2   256 2016-04-28 13:46:34.743 0           LINIE10-4   16  0 - OK  22079362    1       0XAF4C8D9B17C7A24FB9D948FA565A9898      0   1   ZDELINESQL2\DEPRODUCTION    sigma       0
```

I'm out of my possibilities now. I doesn't know what to do. I can't change back to SQL SERVER 2005 of course. I don't suspect netwerk issues because clients didn't change and the new SERVER is also located in the same datacenter as the old one. Both old and new server are virtualized on VMWare.

What can i do? The users live now about 6 weeks with this problems (very patient). Can i further debug the ->Open ADO call? Will a network monitor help? Please suggest?

Greetings, Jörg

Comment: There's a lot to find about *fast in direct call, but slow from application*. This is especially connected to databases which were upgraded from old systems only by scripts... Read about parameter sniffing, `ARITHABORT`, `WITH RECOMPILE`. [Here is a very good article on this](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Comment: It's difficult to debug performance issues when SQL Server is running in a virtual machine. Brent Ozar wrote about this -- https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/03/reasons-why-you-shouldnt-virtualize-sql-server/

Comment: Just try to use metadata query when need get all rows: `SELECT SUM(rows) FROM sys.partitions WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.ProdArtikel')` instead of `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ProdArtikel`

Comment: Another idea, create a index by `lWTNr` column

Comment: What operating system is the SQL Server 2012 running on? You mentioned Windows Server 2003. SQL Server 2012 is supported on Windows Server 2008 SP2 onwards. See Hardware and Software Requirements for Installing SQL Server 2012 -- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Just to add. Current application development is done on XP with Visual Studio 2010

Comment: There is already an index on the lWTNr column. However even without an index, the query should perform quite fast as the table contains max. of about 3000-4000 rows, never more.

Comment: I think just using metadata will not work in my case because the query contains a where condition.

Comment: SQL Server 2012 is running on Windows Server 2012. The old SQL Server 2005 was running on Windows Server 2003. The client computers connecting to the database are still running xp (will be updated this year).